# Spring Boot で作ったプロジェクトとSpring関係のバージョンの調べ方はどのようにすればできますか？

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot

まだ `Spring Boot`についての理解が浅く、`Spring`の開発を楽にしてくれるくらいの認識しかないのですが、https://start.spring.io/ で `Gradle Project`, `Kotlin`を選択しました。

この場合 `build.gradle.kts`にバージョンに関することが記載されていると考えています。

Springには、`Spring Framework(Core)`, `Spring MVC` というように `Spring` と名前のつくものがたくさんあるようですが、おそらく https://start.spring.io/ で作ったプロジェクトに少なくとも `Spring Framework(Core)` と `Spring MVC` は入っているのではないかと推測しています。

この推測が正しいとした場合、`Spring Boot`と`Spring Framework(Core)`, `Spring MVC`のバージョンの関係を知りたいと思いました。 `Spring BootのバージョンHoge` は `Spring Framework(Core)バージョンFoo`を使っている等。

こういった情報はどこにどのように記載されていますでしょうか？

背景としては、フレームワークのバージョンが上がったときにどう対処するのか気になったためですが、`Spring Boot`を使った場合は、細かい `Spring Framework(Core)` のことなど気にせずに、 `Spring Boot`のバージョンだけ追っておけば基本問題なかったりするのでしょうか。

（`Gradle Project`, `Kotlin`を選択しましたが、回答は `Maven Project`や`Java`でもかまいません。本質的には同じと思うので、あとで対応を調べるつもりです）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コード上からは
[`spring-boot-dependencies`の構成ファイル](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.2.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L193)を見ると良いかと思います。

先日リリースされた2.3.0からはMavenから[Gradle(`build.gradle`)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L1636)に変わっているようですね…

---

私は普段Maven+Eclipseで開発しているのでそちらでの例になりますが、
自分のSpring Bootプロジェクトの`pom.xml`を開き `spring-boot-starter-parent`宣言箇所を <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+クリック すれば `spring-boot-starter-parent` の `pom` が開きます。
そこに `spring-boot-dependencies` が宣言されているのでこれまた <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+クリック すればたどり着けます。

Mavenローカルリポジトリは(デフォルトでは) `$HOME/.m2/repository` に作成されるので、
`$HOME/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/<バージョン>/spring-boot-dependencies-<バージョン>.pom`
にこのファイルはあります。

[Gradleの場合](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33196481/4506703)は
`$HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/<バージョン>/<ハッシュ>/spring-boot-dependencies-<バージョン>.pom`
です。

Comment: なるほど。2.3.0からspring boot自体がgradle使うようになったんですね。この構成ファイルはローカルのプロジェクトフォルダーにはありますか？（あった場合、jarとかになっておらず見れますか？）

Comment: よく考えたら、Ruby on Railsと違って、Javaはコンパイルされるのでさすがにローカルで見るのは普通ではない気がしてきました...（失礼しました）

Comment: ありました。ありがとうございます。